Apache Kafka Problems with offset
I'm using confluent kafka library to create a distributed system, but I'm failing to understand some principles of Kafka itself.
Lets say right now I'm working with a Central, that has to listen to different customers.
What i wanna do is that when the program Central is shut off, whatever customer program sends, it won't be received by the Central when I execute this program again. The way I configure it was the following:
PRODUCTOR CUSTOMER TO CENTRAL
producer_conf = {
'bootstrap.servers': f'{broker_ip}:9092',
'retries': 5,
'retry.backoff.ms': 1000
}
self.producer = Producer(producer_conf)
self.requests = self.load_requests(self.request_file)

CONSUMER CENTRAL LISTENING TO CUSTOMER:
consumer_conf = {
'bootstrap.servers': f'{broker_ip}:9092',
'group.id': 'central_group',
'auto.offset.reset': 'latest',
'enable.auto.commit': True,
}
self.consumer = Consumer(consumer_conf)
self.consumer.subscribe(['taxirequests'])  

CREATION OF THE TÓPICO (manually):
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic taxirequests --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Your problem isn’t clear to me. What is central, what’s customer, what’s shut down and what’s listening? Please use standard Kafka jargon (producer, consumer, topic etc.) to state your problem.

Try to add auto.offset.reset=latest and check how it works.
